# Sum of $n^2$ array of $a_ja_k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I'm trying to learn about sums from the book Concrete Mathematics which gives this problem:

We have the array

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1a_1 &  a_1a_2 & \ldots & a_1a_n\\
a_2a_1 &  a_2a_2 & \ldots & a_2a_n\\
\vdots & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_na_1 & a_na_2  & \ldots & a_na_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
of $n^2$ products of $a_ja_k$. And we want to find a simple formula for

$$ S_◹ = \sum_{1 \leq j \leq k \leq n} a_ja_k
$$ 
which is approximately half the the sum of all the elements. Then he manipulate the equation as such:

$$
S_◹ = \sum_{1 \leq j \leq k \leq n} a_ja_k = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq j \leq n} a_ka_j = \sum_{1 \leq k \leq j \leq n} a_ja_k = S_◺
$$

So far so good, but then he manipulates the indices as such:

$$
\label{1}
[ 1 \leq j \leq k \leq n] + [1 \leq k \leq j \leq n] = [1 \leq j,k \leq n] + [1 \leq j=k \leq n]
$$

As far as I can tell from the introduction of the $j,k$ notation it means the permutations over all integers $j$ and $k$. But when I try his manipulation to the indices for small value of $n$ I see that it counts the diagonal twice, so we should subtract the $[1 \leq j=k \leq n]$ instead of adding it. Can someone explain why he used addition?

Comment: In the LHS we summed two times over the diagonal elements, and if we take the sum over $[1\leq j,k\leq n]$ we sum them only one time. So we have to correct this, adding one time the diagonal elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write, using your notations 
\begin{align*}[1\leq j\leq k\leq n]+[1\leq k\leq j\leq n]&=[1\leq j< k\leq n]+[1\leq j=k\leq n]\\
&+[1\leq k< j\leq n]+[1\leq k=j\leq n]\\
&=[1\leq j,k\leq n]+[1\leq k=j\leq n],
\end{align*}
since the first three terms of the RHS of the first equality are exactly $[1\leq j,k\leq n]$.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand that he wanted to sum the diagonal row twice. I forgot to put the final step, but it involves adding S to itself, then after simplifying the RHS divide by two and have an expression for the upper trianglar sum.